# Is UHT better for the environment even if the Tetra Paks aren't recycled

Tags: recycling, environmental-impact, plastic

UHT is well known to be better for the environment, see e.g. https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn27898-so-many-milks-but-do-their-health-claims-really-stack-up/

However, our local council does not recycle the UHT milk cartons (but does recycle plastic bottles). Is it still more sustainable?

I am thinking so because recycling Tetra Paks provides only limited benefit, and plastic bottles can only be recycled so many times anyay; However but I haven't seen any study that considers the benefit of UHT over the cost of unrecycled cartons.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Sustainable Living! I'm not familiar with the abbreviation UHT, but from the article I take it it stands for Ultra-Heat-Treated milk? Am I right in thinking that it's only sold in Tetra-Packs were you live?

Comment: Yes, or long life milk.  The packs look like this https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/productdetails/748595

Comment: Tetra Paks may be more difficult to recycle, but also cost less energy to produce than other forms of packaging. They are also lighter and fit together neatly, again reducing the energy required to transport. Also I would check your local recycling facilities - our local council didn't collect Tetra Paks for a long time, but there were recyling centres within a couple of miles that would take them.